# asp.net read Excel file Unspecified error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to read the excel file and copy the data to SQL using file upload. I uploaded the file to temp location. The files are saved but when I try to read the file I am getting Unspecified Error.

The connection String I am using is:

```
_connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\"", tempfileLoc);

using (OleDbConnection _cn = new OleDbConnection(_connString))
{
  using (OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand())
  {
    using (OleDbDataAdapter _odA = new OleDbDataAdapter())
    {
      _cmd.Connection = _cn;
      _cn.Open();
      DataTable _dtESchema = new DataTable();
      _dtESchema = _cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
      DataTable _dtEColumns = new DataTable();
      _dtEColumns = _cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, "Sheet1$", null });
      var tblname = (_dtESchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"]).ToString();
      _cn.Close();
    }
  }
}

Stack Trace: 
[OleDbException (0x80004005): Unspecified error]
   btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2703
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

The permission to the folder is fine as the file is uploaded and can be accessed from webpage.

If I login as the server Admin account, I can upload the file but if I login as general user, it is throwing the error. The Impersonation is enabled on IIS. the server is Windows 2008 R2.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try opening the file? Is it a valid file? Is `tempfileLoc` a value that you expected? Where is your code that actually runs? This code you've provided wouldn't throw that error.

Comment: Try checking your Application Pool.  Go to Advanced Settings & set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to true

Comment: @mason I have added the code block that is throwing the error. the tempfileLoc is the correct value and I can open the file and read the values. I am not sure why the regular user account cannot open the connection to excel files. the process completes without any error if I use any account that is in Administrator group in the server.

Comment: Have you tried creating the famous Desktop folder in the systemprofile? [Link](https://sudarshanbhalerao.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/excel-application-objectexpects-desktop-folder-under-certain-paths/)

Comment: I created the folder on both the location and still the same error.

Comment: The app pool is running with specific account. So adding the users to access AppData\Local\Temp folder for the user helped on solving the issue.